Remove path in url: from mycompany.com/en to mycompany.com
I own 2 domains (mycompany.com and mycompany.it) which I'd like to use to serve the software (Odoo Community Edition) respectively in English and Italian localization.
The problem is the software (Odoo) performs the multilanguage function like this:

www.mycompany.com/en - English
www.mycompany.com/it - Italian

Instead, I'd to have one domain per language:

www.mycompany.com - English
www.mycompany.it - Italian

I'm using Nginx reverse proxy and I'm trying to rewrite the url from www.mycompany.com/en to www.company.com (same thing for the Italian one) but I'm not able to do it.
This is my configuration:
/etc/nginx/conf.d/www.mycompany.com

#odoo server
upstream odoo {
  server 192.168.1.305:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
  server 192.168.1.305:8072;
}
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

map $sent_http_content_type $content_type_csp {
    default "";
    ~image/ "default-src 'none'";
}


# http -> https
server {
    if ($host = www.mycompany.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.mycompany.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  listen 443 quic;
  listen [::]:443 quic;
  http2 on;

  server_name www.mycompany.com;

 #auth_basic "Restricted";
 #auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;

  # SSL parameters
  #include snippets/self-signed.conf;

  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

  # Redirect websocket requests to odoo gevent port
  location /websocket {
    proxy_pass http://odoochat;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=3600' always;
  }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=3600' always;

    # Enable HSTS
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    # requires nginx 1.19.8
    #proxy_cookie_flags session_id samesite=lax secure;
  }

  location @odoo {
    # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=3600' always;

    # Enable HSTS
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    # requires nginx 1.19.8
    proxy_cookie_flags session_id samesite=lax secure;
  }

  location ~ ^/[^/]+(!db$)/static/.+$ {
      # root and try_files both depend on your addons paths
      root /opt/odoo;
      try_files /16.0/addons$uri /16.0/OCB$uri @odoo;
      expires 24h;
      add_header Content-Security-Policy $content_type_csp;
  }

  location /web/filestore {
      internal;
      alias /root/.local/share/Odoo;
  }


  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mycompany.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mycompany.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
                                                                                  


If I set the proxy_pass http://odoo; to proxy_pass http://odoo/en; it starts an endless loop.
Any ideas?

Edit:
I made some progress: if I use both proxy_pass http://odoo/en/; and rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ https://www.mycompany.com/$1 last; it seeems to work for all the pages except the homepage which it takes me to www.mycompany.com/en. Originally the homepage redirect from www.mywebsite.com/en/en to www.mywebsite.com/en.

Have you tried proxy_pass http://odoo/en/;?

@RichardSmith yes, I did but it send me, the first time on mycompany.com/en on the homepage then mycompany.com/en/en (404 error) while visiting the contact page it throws me on mycompany.com/en/contact which is a 404 error as well.
